# While em lista no python

Tags: python, lista, loop, while

Alguém poderia dar um help com a seguinte dúvida?

em "item", a meta é dar o loop de 0 a 50

```
id_rec = [conteudo['complainResult']['complains']['data'][item]['id']]
```

Eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
item = 0
while item < len(id_rec):
        item = item + 1
```

Porém, só tem retornado o primeiro registro. Como proceder?

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente a lista `id_rec` só tem um item...

Quando você tem uma lista que pertence a outra lista, ela só conta como um elemento... veja o exemplo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [a]

>>> len(a)
4
>>> len(b)
1
```

Comment: Qual seria o caminho, então?

Comment: Depende de qual é o conteúdo de id_rec... Sem saber o que tem não dá pra ajudar

Comment: o conteúdo está sendo puxado desse JSON:

https://iosearch.reclameaqui.com.br/raichu-io-site-search-v1/query/companyComplains/50/0?company=38653&status=ANSWERED&evaluated=bool:false

Comment: só retorna 50 resultados por vez. A ideia é criar a lista com esses 50 registros (alterando o valor item), numa espécie de "for". Entendeu?